# Quel est le sens de « gorge nouée » ?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Je suis en train de lire un roman, et je suis tombé sur l'expression « gorge nouée » dans cet extrait :

> Ceux qui ont changé l'école ont dû connaître ces matinées de septembre
>   où, **gorge nouée**, on ne sait que répondre à ses parents quand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoir la *gorge nouée*, c'est ne plus pouvoir parler, avoir les cordes vocales bloquées, comme si on avait fait un nœud avec la trachée et qu'aucun son ne pouvait passer.

Comment: C'est en général lié aux émotions...

Comment: La gorge s'assèche de par l'angoisse qu'amène l'émotion donnant ainsi l'impression d'avoir la gorge serrée.

Answer (score 2):

Le fait de ne pas pouvoir parler à cause de l'émotion.

Answer (score 2):

Gorge nouée : ne plus pouvoir parler, à cause *d'émotions*, pas uniquement **l'angoisse**, mais aussi la **tristesse**. Par exemple

> C'est la gorge nouée qu'il assistait à ce triste évènement

.